# ASP.NET Core WEB API Config file issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, config, appsettings

I'm not sure whether this issue is related to ASP.NET Core or not.

I define my connectionstrings in the appsettings.json file and publish the API project.

When I execute an endpoint, I get this error:
"No connection string named 'DbContext' could be found in the application config file.", though I have defined the DbContext inside the appsettings.json

The only way to get it working is to specify the connectionstrings inside projectname.exe.config file explicitly. Any idea why this is so? Can't I just specify the connectionstrings in the appsettings.json and it be picked from there when necessary?

Following is my appsettings.json file:

```
{
 "ConnectionStrings": {
"DbConnectionString": "data source=DEV-DB;initial catalog=AmsSystem;user id=sa;password=111111;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework",
"DbContext": "data source=DEV-DB;initial catalog=AmsSystem;user id=sa;password=111111;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework"
},
"AppSettings": {
"AESEncryptionKey": "qgJMnfoVGxwZsl8eELea5/1jqyQJg2mgC/Vb4mUetN4=",
"VirtualDirectory": "/demoapi"
},
"Logging": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"Debug": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
},
"Console": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
}

},
 "JwtSecurityToken": {
"Key": "YouCannotAlterTokenIfYouCannotHoldThisVeryLongKey",
"Issuer": "http://demoserver.com",
"Audience": "http://demoserver.com"
}
 }
```

Program.cs

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddScoped(_ => new DbContext());

        // get the application configuration settings
        var appSettings = config.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppConfig>(appSettings);

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        // Add custom repositories
        services.AddTransient<IModelFactory, ModelFactory>();


        // Add custom services
        services.AddTransient<IAppointmentProvider, AppointmentDataProvider>();
        services.AddTransient<ILogProvider, EventLogProvider>();

        // add the database connection
        services.AddDbContext<SecurityContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString")));

        // add ASP.NET identity service
        services.AddIdentity<ApiUser, ApiRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SecurityContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

Comment: This question isn't making sense. Are you really building an web API? Are you sure it's .Net Core? What does your JSON look like? Have you told your app to use the JSON file? When you publish, is the JSON file being included in the destination folder?

Comment: Yes, it's a web api written in .NET Core. I've updated the question with the json content, and yes, the json is included in the destination folder

Comment: Show us your `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs` please. They should show how you're wiring up the configuration.

Comment: @devC Could you show the code that retrieve the connection string?

Comment: Updated the code snippets.

Comment: @devC Why do you register an instance of `DbContext` in DI container? How do you plan to use it?

Comment: This line `services.AddScoped(_ => new DbContext());` should not be there. You're registering your `SecurityContext` correctly and that uses the `DbConnectionString`. If you have another context to register do it the same way. If the only ef context you have is `SecurityContext` just remove said line.

Comment: public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } 

add these lines of code in Startup.cs file and you should be able to retrieve config values like Configuration.GetSection and GetValue.